# C++ Vector of class - finding the max subindex for a index

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

For any experts out there. Can you please let me the most efficient way to get the desired output?

- Want to fetch the Index/SubIndex values only for the highest subindex records
- Want to get only the index/Subindex for any given input.
- Want to fetch the Indexes for a given Range

Have around 2 million Indexes and for each index there are around 100 SubIndexes. All of them are inserted sequentially(Both Indexes and SubIndexes). Trying to find an efficient way to fetch the desired data. Even I am open to use a different data structure as needed as well as use C++20 Ranges as needed.

Thank you in advance. Would post the final solution if I could find one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class testclass {
public:
   int Index;
   int SubIndex;
   int Data;
   // There are few more elements
};

class DataObject {
   testclass Rec;
};

std::vector<testclass> v;


int main()
{
   testclass Rec;

   Rec.Index = 1;
   Rec.SubIndex = 0;
   Rec.Data = 1;
   v.emplace_back(Rec);

   Rec.Index = 2;
   Rec.SubIndex = 0;
   Rec.Data = 1;
   v.emplace_back(Rec);

   Rec.Index = 2;
   Rec.SubIndex = 1;
   Rec.Data = 2;
   v.emplace_back(Rec);

   Rec.Index = 3;
   Rec.SubIndex = 1;
   Rec.Data = 4;
   v.emplace_back(Rec);

   // Q1 - How to print only the records with highest SubIndex -  Desired output -  1 0 1, 2 1 2 & 3 1 4
   // Q2 - How to fetch the Record for a given Index (to fetch the record of the highest subIndex value for a given Index - example Fetch Index 2 --- Output -- 2 1 2 (Highest SubIndex value)
   // Q3 - How to fetch the records for a given Index Range with Highest SubIndex - Example - Fetch the Indexes from 2 to 3 - Output - 2 1 2 & 3 1 4

   for(auto &i : v) {
       std::cout << i.Index << " " << i.SubIndex << i.Data << "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, the elements of `v` are sorted w.r.t. `auto testclass::operator<=>(testclass) = default;`, Index then SubIndex?

Comment: Caleth - I have updated the original post. The testclass actually has several members. For simplicity sake I have posted only 2 elements. For each of the index elements - there are different SubIndexes which represent different Data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you need a quick search and at the same time keep the sequence of objects.

For this, you can use additional Associative containers.
Sample code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>


class testclass {
public:
    int Index;
    int SubIndex;
};

class RecQuery
{
public:

    /**
     * @brief      Pushes a record.
     *
     * @param[in]  Rec   The record.
     */
    void PushRec(const testclass& Rec)
    {
        m_mapIndexToSubIndexToRecordIndex[Rec.Index][Rec.SubIndex] = m_vecRecords.size();
        m_vecRecords.emplace_back(Rec);
    }

    /**
     * @brief      Finds a record.
     *
     * @param[in]  Index  The index.
     *
     * @return     The reference to the record.
     */
    testclass& FindRecord(const int Index)
    {
        const std::map<int, size_t>& subIndexToRecordMap = m_mapIndexToSubIndexToRecordIndex.at(Index);
        return m_vecRecords[std::rbegin(subIndexToRecordMap)->second];
    }


    /**
     * @brief      Visits the Index/SubIndex values only for the highest subindex records.
     *
     * @param      visitor   The visitor.
     *
     * @tparam     FVisitor  The type of visitor.
     */
    template<typename FVisitor>
    void VisitHighestSubIndexes(FVisitor&& visitor)
    {
        for (const auto& [Index, SubIndexToRecIndex] : m_mapIndexToSubIndexToRecordIndex)
        {
            auto maxIndexIt = std::rbegin(SubIndexToRecIndex);
            visitor(m_vecRecords[maxIndexIt->second]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @brief      Visits all records in the Index range. [from, to]
     *
     * @param[in]  from      The begin of the index range.
     * @param[in]  to        The end of the index range.
     * @param      visitor   The visitor.
     *
     * @tparam     FVisitor  The type of visitor.
     */
    template<typename FVisitor>
    void VisitRangeByIndex(const int from, const int to, FVisitor&& visitor)
    {
        const auto fromIt = m_mapIndexToSubIndexToRecordIndex.find(from);
        if (fromIt == std::end(m_mapIndexToSubIndexToRecordIndex))
        {
            throw std::out_of_range{ "Index not found." };
        }
        auto toIt = m_mapIndexToSubIndexToRecordIndex.find(to);
        if (toIt == std::end(m_mapIndexToSubIndexToRecordIndex))
        {
            throw std::out_of_range{ "Index not found." };
        }

        // If you do not need to visit the last element of the back range, delete this line.
        ++toIt;

        for (auto it = fromIt; it != toIt; ++it)
        {
            visitor(m_vecRecords[std::rbegin(it->second)->second]);
        }
    }


    /**
     * @brief      Returns an iterator pointing to the first record.
     *
     * @return     Iterator to the element.
     */
    auto begin() const noexcept
    {
        return std::begin(m_vecRecords);
    }

    /**
     * @brief      Returns an iterator pointing to the last record.
     *
     * @return     Iterator to the element.
     */
    auto end() const noexcept
    {
        return std::end(m_vecRecords);
    }

private:
    std::vector<testclass> m_vecRecords;
    // for more performance can you use boost::container::flat_map.
    // boost::container::flat_map<int, boost::container::flat_map<int, size_t>> m_mapIndexToSubIndexToRecordIndex;
    std::map<int, std::map<int, size_t>> m_mapIndexToSubIndexToRecordIndex;
};

int main()
{
    RecQuery recQuery;
    testclass Rec;

    Rec.Index = 1;
    Rec.SubIndex = 0;
    recQuery.PushRec(Rec);

    Rec.Index = 2;
    Rec.SubIndex = 0;
    recQuery.PushRec(Rec);

    Rec.Index = 2;
    Rec.SubIndex = 1;
    recQuery.PushRec(Rec);


    // Q1 - How to print only the records with highest SubIndex(Highest) -  Desired output -  1 0 & 2 1
    std::cout << "Q1 ===========================================" << std::endl;
    recQuery.VisitHighestSubIndexes([](testclass& rec)
        {
            std::cout << "Index: " << rec.Index << " Subindex: " << rec.SubIndex << std::endl;
        });
    std::cout << "Q2 ===========================================" << std::endl;
    // Q2 - How to get only a specific Index/Subindex(highest) for a given input value  - 2 1
    testclass rec2 = recQuery.FindRecord(2);
    std::cout << "Index: " << rec2.Index << " Subindex: " << rec2.SubIndex << std::endl;

    // Q3
    std::cout << "Q3 ===========================================" << std::endl;
    recQuery.VisitRangeByIndex(1, 2, [](testclass& rec)
        {
            std::cout << "Index: " << rec.Index << " Subindex: " << rec.SubIndex << std::endl;
        });
    std::cout << "===========================================" << std::endl;


    for (auto& i : recQuery)
    {
        std::cout << i.Index << " " << i.SubIndex << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I used std::map, but it is better if using boost::flat_map. The boost::flat_map example is commented out.

Comment: Thank you Argishti Ayvazyan.  Would check it out.

Comment: -- Thank you for the reply. This code compiles and works fine. Just that I have posted a slightly modified code above - Q2 - Input value is just a single Index.  There is Q3 - to get the data for a given range of Indexes. Could you please help to update the code you have posted? I am also making an attempt to get the desired result and would post If I am successful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you explain a little in detail, preferably there are examples of calls, what are the input values of the function and what are the outputs?

Comment: This is pretty close to the solution I am looking for but unable to complete the rest as the class data has changed slightly along with the queries being slightly different. Could you please help?  thank you.

Comment: Q1 - is complete - It's displaying all the indexes/data for highest subindexes. Q2 - Input is only Index - For this index it needs to return only one record for which highest Subindex is present.  Q3 - Input is Range of Index(Say 2 to 3) - It needs return records for those range of Indexes - All the records needs to have Highest Sub-Index for it's index. Thank you much.

Comment: - THANK YOU so much. The solution works great. Just that I need to change the containers and would work through the logistics. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution you have provided. I could get this working mostly the way I wanted it to be. Would you please elaborate on the PushRec function - m_mapTradesToSubTrades[Rec.TradeNumber][Rec.SubTradeNumber] = m_vecRecords.size();  -- What does it do? Where are you actually storing the pointer to corresponding m_vecRecords  record?  Appreciate your answer.

Comment: I am not storing a pointer, I am storing the index of the Record.
m_vecRecords.size () returns the number of elements in std::vector,  because indexing starts at 0, the number of elements is always one more than the last index. This means that the size will be the index of the element that will be added after that (m_vecRecords.emplace_back (Rec)), after that, I store that in an std::map which will allow me to find this index in logarithmic time.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a transparent compare to find the range of `testclass` instances that share an `Index`, and the end of that range is the highest `SubIndex`

It would actually be easier if your data was ordered in the opposite direction, so we can take the first element of the range, but we can use reverse iterators to do that.

```
struct compare_index {
    using is_transparent = void;
    bool operator()(testclass lhs, testclass rhs)
    {
        return lhs.index > rhs.index;
    }
    bool operator()(int lhs, testclass rhs)
    {
        return lhs > rhs.index;
    }
    bool operator()(testclass lhs, int rhs)
    {
        return lhs.index > rhs;
    }
};

// can swap std::vector for another range here
std::vector<testclass> highest_subindices()
{
    if (v.empty()) { return {}; }
    std::vector<testclass> result;

    auto range = std::equal_range(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), v.back(), compare_index{});
    while (range.second != range.first)
    {
        result.push_back(*range.first);
        range = std::equal_range(range.second, v.rend(), *range.second, compare_index{});
    }
    return result;
}

testclass * highest_subindex(int Index)
{
    auto range = std::equal_range(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), Index, compare_index{});
    return range.first != range.second ? &*range.first : nullptr;
}

// can swap either std::vector for another range here
std::vector<testclass *> highest_subindices(std::vector<int> Indices)
{
    std::vector<testclass> result(Indices.size());
    std::transform(Indices.begin(), Indices.end(), result.begin(), highest_subindex);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Caleth. Appreciate it. Just that I have initially simplified the class with 2 elements. I am going to check this to see if it is possible to expand further and would post the final solution.

Comment: Caleth - I am running into compiler issue for the statement - "generator<testclass> highest_subindices()" - Can you please let me know which headers should be added for this? Preferably compilable would be useful. I am using VS 2019 - if it matters.

Comment: @ejuser It's not a library type, but see the example in [`co_yield`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.yield)

Comment: Thank you. My attempts to have the code compiled didn't yield any results so far. Would explore further and let you know if I can. Thank you much.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide me a compilable code? I tried various options but unable to get this compiled. Thank you.

Comment: The solution provided by Argishti Ayvazyan works fine. Checking this solution as well now to see if it works. Thank you.

Comment: Executed this and Q1 - is missing few Indexes.  Q2 - is correct. Q3 - unknown

Comment: // Q1 - How to print only the records with highest SubIndex(Highest) -  Desired output -  1 0 0 & 2 1 2 & 3 1 4
    for (auto &i : highest_subindices()) {
        std::cout << "Index: " << i.Index << " Subindex: " << i.SubIndex << " Data: " << i.Data << std::endl;   // But this is only printing 3 1 4 & 2 1 2 - missing other Index 1 as well as reverse order
    }

Comment: // Q2 - How to get only a specific Index/Subindex(highest) for a given input value  - 2 1 2   --- This works 
    std::cout << "------Q2 - How to get only a specific Index/Subindex(highest) for a given input value  - 2 1 2----" << std::endl;
    testclass *p_Rec = highest_subindex(2);
    std::cout << "Index: " << p_Rec->Index << " Subindex: " << p_Rec->SubIndex << " Data: " << p_Rec->Data << std::endl;

Comment: // Q3 - How to get the records for an input Range of Indexes?

Comment: This Certainly seems to be an elegant solution if this works(Q1 & Q3) as there is no need to change the container.

Comment: This line is failing compilation   ---  auto highest_subindices(range auto Indices)   - Error - Type auto unexpected(auto in auto Indices). Does it compile for you? I have included the ranges as well range/v3 libraries. Thanks

Comment: Still no luck compiling this. Could you please let me know which compiler do you use and the header libraries - which would allow the compile of the line "auto highest_subindices(range auto Indices) " ? Thanks

Comment: @ejuser was a guess for C++20 ranges